# Can I save data in more that one time for single request in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is model call Event which contains following attributes

> start_at,
>   end_at,
>   details,
>   trainer

This is my normal create method which generated my scaffold command

```
  def create
@event = Event.new(params[:event])

respond_to do |format|
  if @event.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@event, :notice => 'Event was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @event, :status => :created, :location => @event }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @event.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

and I need to modify this as follows when particular event object have date gap between stat_at and end_at more than 6 I need to save that event as two events. First event will started at original started date and end date should be middle date of the event and other data are same. But in second event it should be start date as middle date and end date should have original end date. Can some one explain how could I done this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the line **if @event.save** you can create another Event record like this

Please note this code is untested.

```
if (@event.end_at - @event.start_at) > 6
  event2 = Event.new
  event2.start_at = something
  event2.end_at = anotherthing
  event2.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are going to do some logic, you can write a method to perform your logic and call that method from controller. Better keep the method in Event model to satisfy good practice of Fat Model and Lean Controller.

```
def self.create_event(ev_params)
  status = false
  if event.end_dat - event.stat_dat >6
    # create two events
    event1 = Event.new(ev_params)
    mid_date = event1.stat_at + ((event.end_dat - event.stat_dat)/2).days
    event1.end_at = mid_date
    event2 = Event.new(ev_params)
    event2.stat_at = mid_date
    status = event1.save'
    status = event=2.save'
  else
    status = Event.create(ev_params)
  end
  status      
end
```

And call this method from controller Event.create_event in controller @event.save.

This is not tested code but I hope you can easily get from above code.

Comment: redirecting part should not change much. You just replace in the code above where @event.save with Event.create_event(params[:event]). I suggest you to go thorough Rails Tutorial thoroughly once again

Comment: Can you explain is it correct if I call this method like Event.create_event(@event)

Comment: I try this but it give error call "undefined method `create_event' " How can i resolve that

Comment: This should work if you have defined the above class method in Event class.

Comment: I have define above method in Event class but it gives that error